# browserify jquery + jquery-ui not works for me

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, npm, browserify

i create simple test app to demonstrate my problem

https://github.com/alexey2baranov/jquery-ui-broken-demo

in this demo I first of all intalled jquery and jquery-ui

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

then created simple test script

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
require('jquery-ui');


$(function(){
   $('#qwerty').draggable();
});
```

and compiled them with browserify

```
browserify --debug index.js -o dist/index.js
```

At the last step i loaded browserify result into test html page

```
<head>
    <script src="dist/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="qwerty" style="position: absolute; width: 100px;  height: 100px; background-color: #0b3e6f">123</div>
</body>
```

And got this error in chrome console

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).draggable is not a function
>   TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.  undefined index.js [sm]:10Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not
>   a function

What's wrong with my code??

Comment: Given the error message, for some reason your inclusion of the jQueryUI library has not worked.

Comment: Yap! Hope sombody get the same error and could fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable'

$("#draggable").draggable();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Agreed that more explanation is needed here.
Plus this snippet probably won't work since the imported files will call for `$.ui.mouse` which is not defined.